# copy a selected div and paste it as well as delete

Tags: jquery

i have multiple divs with buttons under them

so what i want to do is when i select on a particular and hit copy div i want to copy that div only and paste it right away. same goes for delete.

how would i be able to achieve this? i am very new at jquery.

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTsDd.png)

what i have tried is this:

```js
    $('#areas').on('click', '.item', function() {
        var thisitem = $(this).clone();
        var thisitemDelete = $(this);
        $(this).css("background-color","gray");
        $( "#copy").click(function(e) {
            thisitem.appendTo("#areas");
        });
        $( "#delete").click(function(e) {
            thisitemDelete.remove();
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="areas">
    <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: blue;">1</div>
    <br>
    <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: red;">2</div>
    <br>
    <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: black;">3</div>
    <br>
    <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: green;">4</div>
</div>
<br>

    <button id="copy">Copy</button>
<br><br>
    <button id="delete">delete</button>
```

but the problem is once something is selected i cant deselect and some more bugs to it you can try on jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kunz/3tr7x14u/1/

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You appear to have mistaken this site as a code writing service. Instead, we expect you to show what you've tried and are failing to get working using a [mcve] (preferably with a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)). Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular... I'd also suggest taking the [tour]

Comment: has been updated since ^

Comment: @D_N yes that was my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a css class to identify the clicked item. When an item is clicked you clear the class from all other items and toggle it for the clicked item. You can then use this to identify the selected item on remove and copy.

e.g.

```js
$("#areas .item").click(function() {
 
  // deselect all other items
  $("#areas .item").not(this).removeClass("selected-item");

  // select/deselect clicked item
  $(this).toggleClass("selected-item");

});

$("#copy").click(function(e) {

  // copy selected item
  $("#areas .selected-item").clone().appendTo("#areas");

});

$("#delete").click(function(e) {

  // remove selected item
  $("#areas .selected-item").remove();

});
```

```css
.selected-item {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="areas">
  <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: blue;">1</div>
  <br>
  <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: red;">2</div>
  <br>
  <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: black;">3</div>
  <br>
  <div class="item" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid; border-color: green;">4</div>
</div>
<br>

<button id="copy">Copy</button>
<br><br>
<button id="delete">delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('#areas').on('click', '.item', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var thisitem = $(this).clone();
    var thisitemDelete = $(this);
    $( "#copy, #delete").unbind('click');
    $( "#copy").click(function(e) {
        thisitem.appendTo("#areas");
        $($this).css("background-color","");
    });
    $( "#delete").click(function(e) {
        thisitemDelete.remove();
        $($this).css("background-color","");
    });
    $(this).css("background-color","gray");
});
```

Comment: (I put his code into a snippet in the question just now, so you could copy that in if you want.)

Comment: its almost there just need to dis-select the gray color when clicked again very close though

Comment: or maybe do not select multiple items thus the div wont be grayed out